# Nested repeated measures analysis

Tags: r, repeated-measures, panel-data, nested-data

I have a nested repeated measures question.  I have 20 individuals grouped into 5 families.  For each individual I have measurements on subsequent days pre, during, and post-treatment for a total of 6 measurements per individual (on days 1 and 2 pre-treatment, on days 4 and 5 during treatment, and days 7 and 8 post-treatment).

I previously used a model with composited pre, during and post-treatment level that looked like this:

```
lme(log(X)~t1+t2, random=~1|family/participant, data=data)
```

where `t1 = -1` for pre-treatment and `t2 = 1` for post-treatment

This allowed me to interpret the slopes on `t1` and `t2` to evaluate the treatment effect.

How do I incorporate the repeated measures within pre-treatment, during and post-treatment?  Visualizing the data suggests correlation between these measurements on subsequent days and there may be a trend (slight up-tick).

Any suggestions on coding in R would be much appreciated!

Comment: You say that you have 8 measurements per individual, but list 6 measurement occasions, can you clarify this?

Comment: Sorry, I have 6 measurements per individual: 2 pre, 2 during, 2 post